# Django get choices value in lazy query

Tags: python, django, django-models

Simple question, is there a way do to something like this :

```
Blog.objects.values('name', 'choices__values')
```

to get the 'second' value of a field with choices, instead of having to :

```
blog.get_choices.display()
```

for each object?

Example model :

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    choices = models.IntegerField(choices = (
        (0, 'choice1'),
        (1, 'choice2),
        (2, 'choice3),
    ))
```

Comment: Please show your models

Comment: For starters, there's no `name` in `Blog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that without querying every objects.

I would suggest,

```
[(x.name, x.get_choices_display(), ) for x in Blog.objects.all()]
```

If you want to one shot it.

If you want to use this on a regular basis you could create a method in yout Blog model.